# My php Watermark function is not working for png image

Tags: php

I am using a PHP function to add my logo as the watermark on images uploaded on my website. But I don't know why my watermark function is not working for png files. however, it works for jpeg files perfectly. this is my PHP function.

```
function watermark($img) {
   global $wm_file, $wm_right, $wm_bottom;

   // image values pulled from config.inc.php
   $logo = './images/' . $wm_file; // path to the watermark.png
   $sp = $wm_right; // spacing from right side
   $sq = $wm_bottom; // spacing from bottom

   $size = getImageSize($img);
   $sizel = getImageSize($logo);
   $imgA = imageCreateFromJpeg($img);
   imageAlphaBlending($imgA, TRUE);
   if($sizel[0] > $size[0] || $sizel[1] > $size[1]) 
   {
      // logo size > img size
      $sizelo[0] = $sizel[0];
      $sizelo[1] = $sizel[1];
      $sizel[0] = ($sizel[0]/2);
      $sizel[1] = ($sizel[1]/2);
   } 
   else 
   {
      $sizelo[0] = $sizel[0];
      $sizelo[1] = $sizel[1];
   }
   $imgBa = imageCreateFromPng($logo);
   $imgB = imageCreateTrueColor($sizel[0], $sizel[1]);
   imageAlphaBlending($imgB, TRUE);
   imageCopyResampled($imgB, $imgBa, 0, 0, 0, 0, $sizel[0], $sizel[1], $sizelo[0], $sizelo[1]);
   imageColorTransparent($imgB, ImageColorAllocate($imgB, 0, 0, 0));
   $perc = 100; 
   imageCopymerge($imgA, $imgB, ($size[0]-$sizel[0]-$sp), ($size[1]-$sizel[1]-$sq), 0, 0, $sizel[0], $sizel[1], $perc);
   unlink($img);
   if(imageJpeg($imgA, $img, 100)) 
   {
      imageDestroy($imgB);
      imageDestroy($imgA);
      return true;
   }
   chmod($img, 0777);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "it doesn't work". Please describe further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that you are using `imageCreateFromJpeg()` as the way to generate the resource for your `$img` that you are passing to the function.

If you pass a jpeg through the function it will work.  If you pass a png it will not.

I recommend using `imagecreatefromstring()` to create all your resources as it is not dependent on the file type.  Like so:

```
$source = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filePath));
```

Another benefit of this is that it will return false if the function fails to create a resource from the file path that you supplied meaning that the file is not an image file.

Now that you have a resource to use for the rest of your code, `imageJpeg()` will save the resource as a jpeg back to the file path.

Hope that helps.

One other side note.  If you intend on using bmp images, the GD library does not have a built in function for bmps.  However on PHP.net, someone did write a `createimagefromBMP()` that works really well.  Also I think that on the latest version of PHP the GD library does now actually have a `createimagefromBMP()` function.

I also see that you are using `unlink()` to delete the image from your directory.  This is not necessary for two reasons.  The `imageJpeg()` will just overwrite the original.  Also, if for some reason your script fails it may delete the image prematurely and you will loose the image without the new one being written.

Please be careful when using `chmod()`, always make sure that you set permissions back to the original permissions when you are done.

```
chmod($img, 777);  //Give broad permissions.

//Do something.

chmod($img, 600(or whatever they were)); //Reset permission back to where they were before you changed them.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just 1 quick confirmation. Do I need to do something with imageJpeg() too?

Comment: Nope.. All you images will be saved as jpegs.

Comment: thanks,, also is it possible to generate them in png.. cause if user upload png image with transparent background it will generate a black background image as jpeg...?

Comment: So you need to write some code that detects what type of image you are using.  Then you can select which php function to use to save the image.  You can do this by `$fileInfo = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($filePath));`